# List all groups where the profile owner is a member?

Tags: views, users, organic-groups

I need to put a block inside the profile page, that shows all the information of the **profile owner**, regardless of the logged in user. (There are some information out there in the forums about how to catch the logged in user´s information).

I need to list all groups where that user is a member of. And I can´t. I´ve tried a lot of combinations, and the last one seemed correct, why isn´t working? What am I missing?:

This is my current configuration:

**Contextual filters**
(author) Usuario: Uid
Provide default value (User UID from URL)

**Relationships**
Content: Author
(author) OG membership: OG membership from User

**Filter criteria**
Content: Type (= Group)

What am I missing? 
Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: what is the result you are getting with this view? and what fields have you added in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a view that comes with OG called "OG User groups". If you clone that view and change the contextual filters to "Content ID from URL", or change your current view to reflect the provided one you should be good.

If you don't have access to the view these values should work:

**Contextual filters**
OG membership: Entity id

**Relationships**
OG membership: Group Node from OG membership

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn´t realize that now in D7 there is this new view "OG user Groups", that did the trick. The configuration is as follows: Contextual filters: (OG membership from OG group) OG membership: Entity id
Relationships: OG group: OG group from Nodo
(node being the OG group) and OG group: OG membership from OG group.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help out.